# undefined is not an object (Evaluating this.props.navigation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to keep touchable opacity at top right in navigation bar, For onPress of touchable opacity. I want to take the user to home page.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        stAccntList: [],
        stUserAccountNo: '',
        stCustNo: '',
        resp: '',
    };


}
static navigationOptions = {
    //  title: 'myacc',
    title: 'My Accounts',
    headerRight: <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('home');
    }}>
        <Image style={{ marginRight: 20 }} source={require('../../../resources/toolbar/home_inactive.png')} />
    </TouchableHighlight>,
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: colors.themeColor,
        //  top: 30
    }
}
```

It's throwing red screen with above error. Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What do you expect `this` to refer to in `this.props.navigation.navigate('home');` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is work :)

```
         static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
                title: 'My Accounts',
                headerRight: <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate('home');
                }}>
                <Image style={{ marginRight: 20, height: 30, width: 30 }}
source={{ uri:https://media.freepik.com/accounts/img/badges/downloads_gold.png' 
    }} />
                </TouchableHighlight>,
                headerTintColor: 'white',
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: colors.themeColor,
                    //  top: 30
                }
            })
```

Comment: buddy. Syntax error after adding your code .. Some red marks in editor.

Comment: I was update navigationOptions . it is work %100 @KartiikeyaBaleneni

Comment: *"Try this it is work"* Why? What's the problem with the OP's code? What did you change?

Comment: @FelixKling  I was created new RN project. I have two screens. Account and  Home. Then I added navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {....} on both screens. it threw an error. I change navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({.....}); then its work. if it is not work, find me ;)

Comment: What makes you think that `navigationOptions` should be assigned a **functioin**?

Comment: @FelixKling , kartiikeya said that it does not work. I think to solve this different method. What do you think?